# Show that there exist simple measurable functions $s_n$ on X such that $s_n (x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$, for every $x \in X$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose $(X, \sigma)$ algebra is a measurable space. (I don't know how to type m notation meaning sigma algebra). $f: X \to R$ is measurable, and $0 \leq f(x) \leq 1$ for each $x \in X$. Show that there exist simple measurable functions $s_n$ on X such that $s_n (x) \to f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$, for every $x \in X$.

How to do this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix $n \in \mathbb N$. Let's denote by $A_k$ set $\{x\in X: k/n \le f(x) < (k+1)/n\}$. Obviously, $X = \bigcup_{k = 0}^n A_k$, and these sets are disjoint. Now let $s_n = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{k}{n}\chi_{A_k}$, where $\chi_A$ is the characteristic function of $A$ (i.e. $\chi_A(x) = 1$ if $x \in A$ and $\chi_A(x) = 0$ if $x \notin A$). Thus, $s_n$ is a simple function. You can easily prove that $s_n(x) \le f(x) \le s_n(x) + 1/n$ for all $x \in X$.

Thus, the sequence $s_n$ that is constructed in the foregoing way converges to $f$ (even uniformly).

Comment: Can you tell me why these sets are disjoint?